# How to highlight email html text in Google Apps Script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I'm using a script to email a confirmation after a google form is filled out.  I am using HTML in the email and want to highlight a few lines in yellow.  I am using the code below but am receiving an error that the line is missing a ";" before the statement.  Any ideas?

```
 + "<h2><b><span style="background-color:yellow;">Content</span></b></h2> " + "<br/>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to either escape your quotes with backslashes or use apostrophes instead for the HTML attributes.

Also, there's probably no reason to break out the `<br>` tag as you have.

```
+ "<h2><b><span style='background-color:yellow;'>Content</span></b></h2> <br/>"
```