# Highlighting text in a google sheet cell using HTML and google apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am relatively new to scripts and code and am trying to learn some new skills but what I need here is very confusing.

I have a script running which is essentially an independent mail merge. It references a cell in my google doc as a template, which has been formatted as HTML. In this template, I have a footer to the email which is a quote that I would like to be highlighted when the email is sent out.

Here is the script;

```
  function sendEmail() { 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Emails").activate();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ss.getLastRow();

var templateText = 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EmailTemplates").getRange(1, 1).getValue();

var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();

if((lr-1) > quotaLeft){
Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " email quota left for the day and you are trying to send " + (lr-1) + " emails. 0 emails were sent"); 
} else {

for (var i = 3;i<=lr;i++){

var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
var SiteURL = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
var FirstName = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();

var messageBody = templateText.replace("{{First Name}}",FirstName);
var subjectline = "Looking to partner with " + ;
var imageUrl = "place site url here"

var htmlBody = messageBody + "<br><img src='" + imageUrl + "'>";

MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectline, messageBody, {htmlBody: htmlBody});



} // close for loop

}  // close else statement

}
```

The footer of the email which I would like to be highlighted is this;

> “Google only loves you when everyone else loves you first”

Is this possible?

Comment: This is possible, look at how to change the background colour of html text. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434408/how-to-highlight-email-html-text-in-google-apps-script

Comment: thanks for the guidance. I managed to use that to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
+"<p style='color: purple'>Google only loves you when everyone else loves you first</p>";
```

This allowed me to change the text color only